# Using structure binding to change the value of a custom structure

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I am trying to find out a way to change the value of a custom structure using structured binding .I was able to do with `std::map`.I referred few materials from 
[Structured binding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

In the below code I was able to change the value of a map . I want to change the value of `unsigned salary` from defaulted 1000 to 10000

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

struct employee {
    unsigned id;
    int roll;
    std::string name;
    std::string role;
    unsigned salary=1000;
};
int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, int> animal_population {
        {"humans", 10},
        {"chickens", 11},
        {"camels", 12},
        {"sheep", 13},
    };
    std::cout<<"Before the change"<<'\n';
    for (const auto &[species, count] : animal_population)
    {
        std::cout << "There are " << count << " " << species
        << " on this planet.\n";
    }
    for (const auto &[species, count] : animal_population)
     {
        if (species=="humans")
        {
            animal_population[species]=2000;
        }

     }
     std::cout<<"After the change"<<'\n';
     for (const auto &[species, count] : animal_population)
     {
            std::cout << "There are " << count << " " << species
            << " on this planet.\n";
     }

    std::vector<employee> employees(4);
    employees[0].id = 1;
    employees[0].name = "hari";
    employees[1].id = 2;
    employees[1].name = "om";


    for (const auto &[id,roll,name,role,salary] : employees) {
        std::cout << "Name: " << name<<'\n'
        << "Role: " << role<<'\n'
        << "Salary: " << salary << '\n';
    }

}
```

Output

```
Before the change
There are 12 camels on this planet.
There are 11 chickens on this planet.
There are 10 humans on this planet.
There are 13 sheep on this planet.
After the change
There are 12 camels on this planet.
There are 11 chickens on this planet.
There are 2000 humans on this planet.
There are 13 sheep on this planet.
Name: hari
Role: 
Salary: 1000
Name: om
Role: 
Salary: 1000
Name: 
Role: 
Salary: 1000
Name: 
Role: 
Salary: 1000
```

Change  I tried to get expected output

Error I got

> Cannot assign to variable 'salary' with const-qualified type 'const
>   int'

```
for (const auto &[id,roll,name,role,salary] : employees) {
    //employees[].salary = 10000; //not working
    // salary = 10000;            //not working
    std::cout << "Name: " << name<<'\n'
    << "Role: " << role<<'\n'
    << "Salary: " << salary << '\n';
}
```

Expected Output

```
Before the change
There are 12 camels on this planet.
There are 11 chickens on this planet.
There are 10 humans on this planet.
There are 13 sheep on this planet.
After the change
There are 12 camels on this planet.
There are 11 chickens on this planet.
There are 2000 humans on this planet.
There are 13 sheep on this planet.
Name: hari
Role: 
Salary: 10000
Name: om
Role: 
Salary: 10000
Name: 
Role: 
Salary: 10000
Name: 
Role: 
Salary: 10000
```

Thanks in Advance for any solution and suggestion

Comment: I guess it should be non-const reference if you want to modify it

Comment: Any idea how to do that @FilipKočica

Comment: Thanks it solved it :) Not sure whether to delete this question?

Comment: Maybe somebody else would have same question. Since its `c++17` and there arent threads about this issue you shouldnt remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that your values have `const` cvalifier. They are unmodificable.

Remove `const` and use reference `&` so you can modify these variables.

```
for (auto &[id,roll,name,role,salary] : employees) {
    salary = 10000;
    std::cout << "Name: " << name<<'\n'
    << "Role: " << role<<'\n'
    << "Salary: " << salary << '\n';
}
```

Comment: same const was with map but it allowed to change the value

Comment: @HariomSingh; Not exactly. With the map use case, you changed the value through the map, so you never directly changed the `count` variable.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks I am loving this structured binding

Comment: Just for info. It was possible even since `c++17` with [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: I have meant 'before' in previous comment tho.